# How to check if a Google Sheets cell contains any of the values of a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: google-sheets

I have an multi-dimensional array in the following form:

```
var name = [
  ["John", "1"],
  ["Jane", "2"],
  ["Mork", "3"],
  ["Mindy", "4"],
];
```

How to check if a Google Sheets cell contains any of the names in this array and tells me what name it matched or the second value in the array (two separate formulas)?

Comment: That can be done with a plain vanilla spreadsheet formula using `index()`, `match()` and `tocol()`. If you need an Apps Script solution, use `Range.getValues()` and `Array.filter()`. Add the [google-apps-script] tag and an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: Thank you @doubleunary. This really helps

Comment: Posting it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done with a plain vanilla spreadsheet formula using [index()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3098242), [match()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378) and [tocol()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258).

If you need to do the same with Apps Script, use [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).